# iPhone - AVAudioRecorder - how can I record to an mp3?

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudiorecorder

I am using the AVAudioRecorder class available with the 3.0 SDK to record audio in my app.
I am successfully able to record to a caf/aiff file. But I would like to record to an mp3.

I tried changing some values in the settings dictionary but all I get is a blank file.

1. Is it possible to record to an mp3 using AVAudioRecorder
2. If not, how can I transfer the caf files from my app to a computer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From all I can find on the API documentation, you can't change the encoder. The only encoder settings I could find that you can change are:

```
AVEncoderAudioQualityKey;
AVEncoderBitRateKey;
AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey;
```

As for transferring the file, a typical approach would be to email the file.

Comment: A 3-4 minute caf file would be about 30-40 MB! How can we email such a big file? How does the FourTrack app let user access the wav files using IP address? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: doesn't bit rate imply something like MP3/AAC?

Comment: typically yes, but not just mp3, or even audio.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate#Bitrates_in_multimedia

Answer (score 2):

See:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1615.html

IMA is a 4:1 format, which means it will compress to 25% of the original size. It's good enough for voice, but not ideal for music.

Lossless is great for music, but usually only gets 50%.

µLaw and aLaw are older formats that compress to 50%, but are much worse than Lossless.

I haven't used iLBC.

I'd bet you'll never see an MP3 encoder made available to third-party apps due to licensing issues.

Comment: iLBC is good for voice recording. It runs about 7MB for an hour of recording.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to include your own MP3 encoder. And you might not be able to do the encoding in real-time. Sad, but there it is.

Comment: what about m4a? The new voice memo app included with the 3.0 saves the memos in m4a format. So will the AVAudioRecorder also allow saving .m4a files? Thanks

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1615.html
This Q&A talks about recording a compressed CAF file, but doesn't mention m4a as a possibility. If you're recording voice data, one of the listed voice-quality encoders will save a lot of space over uncompressed audio. For high-quality recordings, Apple Lossless will be roughly 50% of the size of uncompressed data.