# MonoTouch: Record audio in compressed format like .m4a

Tags: xamarin.ios

I tired this example: 
http://wiki.monotouch.net/HowTo/Sound/How_to_record_sound_using_the_iPhone_microphone

But when I change the AudioFileType, from a compressed type (MP3) the file size is the same as WAVE.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the list of encoders exposed by iOS:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1615.html

And it does not support MP3 encoding

This was previously discussed here:

[iPhone - AVAudioRecorder - how can I record to an mp3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052092/iphone-avaudiorecorder-how-can-i-record-to-an-mp3)

The only alternative is for you to include your own MP3 encoder and negotiate directly with the MP3 patent holder the terms.

Comment: Miguel, Thanks for the info.  From what I've been able to find on the internet is that you need to use InputAudioQueue.  But I can't seem to find any MonoTouch documentation/examples on how to use it.  When I look at Apples documentation on Audio Queue Services all the Objective - C starts to make my head spin 1/3rd in.  Can you point me to a good example on recording with the mic using InputAudioQueue?  Thanks. - R